# electricity no power in 3 outlets located in my living room

Tags: electrical

I have 3 outlets that are not working. When I use a meter and it reads red to the left and yellow far right? I checked the circuit breaker and it's not tripped? I don't have a GFCI outlet, just standard outlets. When I plug my lamp in I get no power or anything. I still have all power in the entire rest of the house. I continue to switch breakers off and on in the panel still nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Does _"red to the left and yellow far right"_ mean the readout on a [receptacle tester](http://www.idealindustries.ca/products/test_measurement/electrical_testers/receptable_testers.php)?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a bad connection in a receptacle somewhere in the circuit. The problem is almost certainly in the first dead receptacle or the last working one if the circuit is wired in a typical modern fashion (wired one to the next).

I have no idea what you mean by *"i use a meter and it reads red to the left and yellow far right?"*, but you need to check for voltage to the circuit neutral. It is also possible for the hot (live) side to be connected, but the neutral to be open, which will give you a live reading but the circuit itself will still show as dead.